# Docker compose in Azure: Can't connect to database

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to get [SteVe OCPP server](https://github.com/RWTH-i5-IDSG/steve) to run in an Azure Container Instance.  But the web application won't connect to the database when running `docker-compose up` in an Azure ACI context.  It runs just fine locally.

Here's the docker compose file:

```
version: "3.0"

volumes:
  db-data:
    external: false

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: stevedb
      MYSQL_USER: steve
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: changeme
  web:
    image: rainmakers/steve:latest
    links:
      - "db:mariadb"
    ports:
      - 8180:8180
      - 8443:8443
    depends_on:
      - db
```

This is the only thing I'm getting in the web service logs:

```
2021/11/23 13:20:57 Waiting for: tcp://mariadb:3306
2021/11/23 13:20:57 Problem with dial: dial tcp: lookup mariadb on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host. Sleeping 1s
2021/11/23 13:20:58 Problem with dial: dial tcp: lookup mariadb on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host. Sleeping 1s
2021/11/23 13:20:59 Problem with dial: dial tcp: lookup mariadb on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host. Sleeping 1s
2021/11/23 13:21:00 Problem with dial: dial tcp: lookup mariadb on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host. Sleeping 1s
2021/11/23 13:21:01 Problem with dial: dial tcp: lookup mariadb on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host. Sleeping 1s
2021/11/23 13:21:02 Problem with dial: dial tcp: lookup mariadb on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host. Sleeping 1s
2021/11/23 13:21:03 Problem with dial: dial tcp: lookup mariadb on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host. Sleeping 1s
```

This continues for a minute, before the service terminates.

Any idea how to proceed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I geuss you should connect with `http://db:3306` instead of `mariadb:3306`.

By default `Docker Compose` version 3 uses the service name as hostname of [inter-container networking](https://medium.com/@datails/full-stack-development-with-docker-compose-c517ec826696).

Comment: Looks like it worked...   Any idea why `db` instead of `mariadb`?

Comment: because by default docker-compose 3 uses the service name in your `docker-compose.yml` as hostname, see an article about it: https://medium.com/@datails/full-stack-development-with-docker-compose-c517ec826696

Comment: If it works, can you mark it as answered

Comment: I ended up renaming the service to `mariadb` instead of changing all the connection strings.  It was an easier fix.  But thanks for the help!